# Python: Finding common links between Pandas Dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-mining

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
ID                  Text
12             [Apple, Zebra]
14             [Camel, Apple]
18             [Obama, Trump]
20             [Lincoln, Obama, Trump]
15             [Apple, Banana, Zebra]
```

"Text" is a list of strings. I am looking for a way to find the links between rows based on Text, such as ID 12 and 14 have  Apple in common.

So what I would ideally like to have is:

```
ID         Text            Link
12     [Apple]             [14]
12     [Apple, Zebra]      [15]
18     [Obama, Trump]      [20]
```

What I have tried so far: Iterating through each element of each list and making a dictionary like so:

```
{ 'Apple' : [12, 14], 'Obama' : [18, 20], 'Trump' : [18, 20], 'Zebra' : [12, 15], 'Camel' : [14], 'Lincoln' : [20], 'Banana' : [15] }
```

However, since the data is quite big, this takes a lot of time. I am looking for an speed optimized way to do this. Any thoughts and/or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do set math. 
Instead of iterating iterating through each element of each list you could find the union of sets.
```
seta = {1,2,3}

setb = {3,4,5}

if seta intersection setb:

```
log it somewhere as a tuple
```

otherwise:

```
skip it.
```

```
This is O (n^2). I'm not sure how it compares to your current solution. 
Mind sharing it?

Comment: My current solution is quite simple really, I push elements into the dictionary with their IDs("Link"), as tuples, and check whether they are already in there. In which, case I add the ID to the list - "Link". The time complexity would be O(n^2) in the number of elements.

Comment: I don't fully understand your solution though, do you mean I should make each "Text" list as an intersection and check for intersections between that and the rest? But that seems to be O(n^2) in the number of rows!